# FirebaseFireStore return true for isSuccess after I try to delete a document that already created

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I accidentally found this after I test my application. I have a recycleListView that contains cardview which each one has a document from firestore. After I delete some document randomly, it disappear from FirebaseFirestore, but when I try to delete it again it still return isSuccess() true. Can someone explain me why this happen?

This is my code that I use to delete document from Collection.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Collection_A")
    .document(list[position].id).delete().apply {
     addOnCompleteListener { task ->
     if (task.isComplete){
         Log.d("Complete", "Task complete")
     }
     if (task.isSuccessful) {
         Log.d("Complete", "Task complete and Success")
     } else {
         Log.d("Complete", "Task complete but not success")
     }
}
addOnCanceledListener {
    Log.d("Cancel", "Delete data canceled")
}
addOnFailureListener { ex ->
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

### My Document Structure

Collection_A

- > Docoument… [Document ID generated randomly]
  >
  > - > name   [field]: String
  > - > count  [field]: Int
  > - > dateInWeek [field]: Map < String, Boolean >

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and your database structure with an example of such a document.

Comment: I'm already add my code and sample data structure. :)

Comment: I don't understand what is the `apply` call after the `delete()` call and what is the value of `list[position].id` or how is that list defined. I might be better if you provide a screenshot of your database.

Answer (score 1):

I just quickly tested and it seems that on JavaScript too the delete is considered successful even if the document no longer exists. So it sounds like this is working as expected, and you should probably label it as "the task is successful when the document no longer exists in the database". The task will only fail if you don't have permission to delete the document (whether it exists or not).

If you want to test whether a document exists, use a `get()` operation.

If you want to atomically detect whether the document exists and delete it, use a transaction.